# If I compile from source, how can I change default wallet and daemon 10-block lock time?

Tags: monerod, source, build, github

Before I go further, I'll point out:

1. This is procedure could put one's privacy at risk.
2. This would cause a tx to fail more often in the case of a chain reorg.
3. There's likely more than two consequences of doing this. (Feel free to point them out.)

---

Let's say I'm comfortable with cloning the git repo and building Monero from the source code.  Let's also say that I want to experiment with the occasional item here and there, and my current curiosity is the 10-block lock time.  What variable(s) in the code requires editing to change this value?  Further, in what file(s) can I find where this variable is set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that's required is to change one [line of code](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/ed09652a174e80cff78f0bfb9e586292d4a1575f/src/cryptonote_config.h#L48) in the `cryptonote_config.h`:

```
#define CRYPTONOTE_DEFAULT_TX_SPENDABLE_AGE             10
```

and build with the new value.

Comment: I guess it's worth noting that this is unwise in common practice, at least for transacting on mainnet.