# Sending Monero to multiple integrated addresses

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, payment-id, integrated-address, available-outputs

We want to transfer monero to multiple integrated address so we don't have extra payment ids.

So we don't want

```
transfer <address_1> <amount_1> <address_2> <amount_2> <address_3> <amount_3> <payment_id>
```

but we want something like

```
transfer <integrated_address_1> <amount_1> <integrated_address_2> <amount_2>
```

The reason is that we are trying to do this just because after doing a transfer we need to wait 20 or 30 minutes before the transaction is completed by the Monero network, we want fast multiple transactions, otherwise we need to wait for a transaction then can do the second one, so please suggest me something or tell me to do a transfer with multiple addresses.

Answer (score 4):

When you send funds to an integrated address, what you're actually doing is sending funds to the recipient's underlying Monero wallet address and simultaneously attaching an encrypted payment ID to the transaction.

According to the current specification, there can only be one payment ID specified in the tx_extra field. Because of this, only one integrated address can be sent to per transaction.

Unless you can convince the developers of Monero wallets to allow a new tx_extra format that allows multiple encrypted payment IDs to be specified, you're going to have to find a different way of achieving the result you're looking for.

One solution is to "dice up" your outputs ahead of time. If you have one large output of value 100 XMR, then when you spend 1 XMR you'll have to wait for 10 confirmations before your 99 XMR change is available to be spent in a subsequent transaction. But if you do:

```
transfer your_wallet_address 20 your_wallet_address 20 your_wallet_address 20 your_wallet_address 20
```

Then you'll end up with 4 outputs for 20 XMR in your wallet and 1 change output of slightly less than 20 XMR in your wallet (because of the transaction fee).

Therefore you'll be able to send several transactions in a row, each to a different integrated address, and you won't have to wait because you'll be spending from your unlocked balance in future transactions instead of from your locked change balance.

Comment: So there is no way?

Comment: There is no way to send to multiple integrated addresses in the same transaction.

Comment: when i try to do a transaction after that i get unlocked balance is 0.000000000so i need to wait. For this how can i do multiple transaction in a short time with integrated address

Comment: You need to wait for 10 confirmations after dicing your outputs. But once they're diced, you can make lots of integrated address transactions in quick succession because you'll not be waiting for change to become unlocked. It's like splitting a $10 bill into ten $1 bills. Now you can make lots of small transactions in a row without waiting for the change to return to you each time.

Comment: By doing this there is a transaction fees taken, so can you please give me another way to do transaction in short time.

Comment: There is no other way, except for this: If you're willing to tolerate the possibility of failed transactions (due to blockchain reorgs) and the certain loss of transaction untraceability, then you can modify and recompile the Monero wallet software after changing the unlock time preset. See https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4591/if-i-compile-from-source-how-can-i-change-default-wallet-and-daemon-10-block-lo and build instructions here: https://github.com/monero-project/monero Note that this is not recommended because it also hurts the untraceability of other people's transactions.

Answer (score 2):

While, according to other answers here, you can't send to multiple integrated addresses, you can send to multiple subaddresses according to this:

https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/8285/7267

Subaddresses can serve the same purpose that integrated addresses serve, more or less.